# Video disappears from URL when generating preview image after recompiling app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a video app where a user records a video and adds some additional information. The user can then the video and its information on a separate screen.

On the information screen I'm trying to display a still from the video. This works if I open the information screen within that session, but when I recompile and run the application the screen shots no longer appear. I get the following error:

`NSUnderlyingError=0x162b9350 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server.`

The video is on the device somewhere as I can view it via the built in 'Photos' app.

Im using the following code to perform the saving of the url string and for generating the preview image.

**Saving the video url**

```
    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)        
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    let dataPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("-cached.MOV")
    videoData.writeToFile(dataPath, atomically: false) 
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dataPath, forKey: "dataPath")

    videoNote.url = dataPath
```

**Creating preview image**

```
// filePathLocal == videoNote.url
func videoSnapshot(filePathLocal: NSString) -> UIImage? {

    let vidURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:filePathLocal as String)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: vidURL, options: nil)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    let timestamp: CMTime = asset.duration

    var error: NSError?

    if let imageRef = generator.copyCGImageAtTime(timestamp, actualTime: nil, error: &error){
        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    } else {
        print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I never managed to get the code from the `videoSnapshot()` method to work, I found that I could use the following to generate a preview shot. The downside is there is not control over the timestamp that the image is taken from.

```
    ALAssetsLibrary().assetForURL(nsURL, resultBlock: { (asset) -> Void in
        if let ast = asset {
            return image = UIImage(CGImage: ast.defaultRepresentation().fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue())
        }
    })
```